# A quadric has the origin as centre if and only if its equation has no terms of degree $1$

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry, quadrics

I'd like to know how to prove that if a(n affine) quadric of A^n (regarded as the affine space canonically associated to K^n, being a field) has the origin as centre, then its equation has no terms of degree $1$.

Comment: Using its symmetry in the origin as centre?

Comment: What happens if you substitute $x\to-x$, $y\to-y$, $z\to-z$?

Comment: I updated the question making it more specific. The substitution appears useful to me only for the converse implication, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Please add what thoughts you have on the problem or what progress attempt you have made.

Comment: I know this is equivalent to prove that if the set of roots of a polynomial of degree 2 on n variables with coefficients over a field is closed under opposite (that is, if a n-uple x is a root, then -x is also a root), then the polynomial has no linear terms. I could prove this under the stronger hypothesis that the polynomial has equal evaluations on x and -x for every n-uple x: it’s sufficient then to evaluate it on on each element of the canonical basis of K^n and on its opposite, then taking the difference leads to say that 4 times the linear coefficient is zero.

Comment: @TonyMathew In the field Z/2Z the implication is not true: for example, the polynomial in X^2+X+1 has no roots, therefore its set of roots is closed under opposite, but it indeed has a 1-degree term. So one may want to assume that the characteristic is not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{q}\in V[x]$ be a vector in the two-dimensional vector space $V[x]$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$\vec{q}(x)=(x,ax^2+bx+c)
$$
For $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. It can be geometrically shown that the set $Q\subseteq V$ defined by:
$$Q=\{\vec{q}(x)\in V[x]| x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
has an axis of symmetry passing through $\vec{q}(0)=(0,c)$ iff $\vec{q}(x)=\vec{q}(-x)$. Assume this is the case, and observe that $\vec{q}$ can be rewritten as $\vec{q}=\vec{e}+\vec{o}$, where $\{\vec{e},\vec{o}\}\subseteq V[x]$ are defined as:
$$\vec{e}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{q}(x)+\vec{q}(-x))$$
$$\vec{o}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{q}(x)-\vec{q}(-x))$$
We observe that $\vec{o}(-x)=-\vec{o}(x)$, so:
$$\vec{q}(x)=\vec{q}(-x)\Leftrightarrow \vec{o}(x)\text{ is constant}$$
But the only way that $\vec{o}$ can be constant is if $b=0$, so:
$$\vec{q}(x)=(x,ax^2+c)$$
To prove the general case for an arbitrary affine plane $A$ we recall that $V\cong A$ for every $A$, so there is an isomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow V$ showing:
$$\phi(Q')=Q$$
For a unique $Q'\subseteq A$, and a similar argument holds for every $\phi^{-1}(\vec{q})\in Q'$